# When does data become initialized using Jaxb?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a textfield object that I marked not be mapped to using XmlTransient.
When I create the textfield object and pass a string into it. The textfield thinks the string is null.  My question is does the string I am passing into the textfield get mapped first or does it happen after my transient object?

```
public class INDEX {   
    @XmlTransient    
    public TextField contenttext = new TextField(getContent());
    private String content;    
    private Map<QName,String> attributes = new HashMap<QName,String>();    

    public String getContent() {    
        return content;    
    }
    @XmlValue    
    public void setContent(String content) {    
        this.content = content;    
    }

    public Map<QName,String> getAttributes() {    
        return attributes;    
    }    
    @XmlAnyAttribute    
    public void setAttributes(Map<QName,String> attributes) {    
        this.attributes = attributes;    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `contenttext` field is going to be populated with an instance of `TextField` as soon as the class it belongs to (`INDEX`) is instantiated.  At this point the `content` property is `null`.  Then once the class has been instantiated JAXB will populate the values of the mapped fields and properties from the unmarshal operation.